# Sorting an array of objects by a child's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects and I need to sort them based on their child's `average_score` attribute. I've tried with `sort!` but this doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure I can use Rails associations here:

```
collection.sort! do |a, b|
  a.children.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.average_score <=> b.children.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.average_score
end
```

Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be and what is the result? Or are you getting an error?

Comment: you should use sort_by, but Ruby will be much slower that SQL...

Comment: I want it to sort collection based on the child's average_score. The error I'm getting is `undefined method `average_score' for nil:NilClass`. I think this is because some of the objects in the collection don't have children so I did try to allow for nil results but with nil success

Comment: @tokland - I looked at using sort_by but I wasn't sure I could do it this way either. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.sort_by do |x|
  x.children.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.average_score
end
```

Though I'd look for a pure and faster SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

When a, b are instances of User, I'd do this

```
class User
  has_many :children

  # This still looks smelly, has many children
  # but only getting score of first one?
  def children_average_score
    first_child = self.children.where(:user_id => self.id).first

    return first_child.nil ? 0 : first_child.average_score
  end
end
```

And then your sort:

```
collection.sort! do |a, b|
  a.children_average_score <=> b.children_average_score
end
```

Comment: Actually a and b are not instances of User, the children belong to User and another model. The association is one to one in the scope of both models together.

Comment: Your method still applies, I'd just need to pass in current_user.